# Java why isn't the socket listening on the local port I specified in the constructor / bound to?

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, udp

I'm having a weird problem, let's consider the following code :

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class Main{

   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception   {
      Inet4Address myIp = (Inet4Address)Inet4Address.getByName(Main.getLanIp());
      InetSocketAddress myAddr = new InetSocketAddress(myIp, LocalportNumber);
      if(myIp == null){
          throw new Exception();
      }
      DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(myAddr);
      socket.setReuseAddress(true);
      InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("239.xxx.xxx.xxx");
      byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
      byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
      String sentence = "PAYLOAD";
      sendData = sentence.getBytes();
      DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, distantPortNumber);
      DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, 1024);
      socket.send(sendPacket);
      System.out.println("Packet sent");
      socket.receive(receivePacket);
      String modifiedSentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());
      System.out.println("FROM SERVER:" + modifiedSentence);
      socket.close();
   }

   static public String getLanIp() throws SocketException{
        InetAddress inet_addr = null;
        NetworkInterface cur = null;

        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); interfaces.hasMoreElements();){
            cur = interfaces.nextElement();
            try {
                if (cur.isLoopback())
                {
                    continue;
                }
            } catch (SocketException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("interface " + cur.getName());

            for (InterfaceAddress addr : cur.getInterfaceAddresses()){

                inet_addr = addr.getAddress();

                if ( !( inet_addr instanceof Inet4Address)){
                    continue;
                }

                System.out.println("  address: " + inet_addr.getHostAddress() + "/" + addr.getNetworkPrefixLength());
                System.out.println("  broadcast address: " + addr.getBroadcast().getHostAddress());
            }
        }
        return inet_addr.getHostAddress();
    }
}
```

Execution trace :
"""
interface eth0
  address: 192.168.0.20/24
  broadcast address: 192.168.0.255
Packet sent
"""

When I run the preceding code, a packet is sent, the server answers but I still block on the receive method, I can see the incoming packet on wireshark reaching my computer. But when I try a : "netstat -npl", I see a java process listening on the port localPort. I tried a "nc -vvv -u  9393" from remote (lan) and then typed random sentences ... Nothing happened. I tried the same on local (with my external IP, with my loopback IP), same problem. Is there a list of known problems which could block the received udp packets between the kernel and the jvm ?

Comment: Have you tried binding the Socket to `loopback:9393` instead of LAN IP?

Comment: I don't want it to bind it on the loopback interface, I tried the nc on loopback only because I was desperate.

Comment: Then bind it to `Inet4Address.ANY` (not sure about name, but it will be something alike). This means accept UDP packets from ANY other IP adress.

Comment: Binding with the constructor doesn't change anything right ?

Comment: It's been a while since I last looked into UDP networking but I think it in fact DOES cause the bind() and thus does influence the accepted packets. EDIT: [here you go, I was right](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#DatagramSocket%28java.net.SocketAddress%29)

Comment: There's no Inet4Address.ANY, I used the wildcard ip address 0.0.0.0. The program is unblocked when I nc on localhost but not on my lan IP. And I have to use my lan IP.

Comment: Turns out Java doesn't have any constant adresses (sucks) :/ Had success with that?

Comment: Yes I found out, I'm editing the question ... It's so dumb, I was stuck 3 days on that ... So ashamed.

Comment: How can I mark the question as resolved ?

Comment: You must post an answer to it (yourself here, since I didn't answer it) and accept it (2 days waiting time before you can accept your own answer).

Comment: I have to wait 8 hours after I asked. So I'm leaving the edit for now and I will answer tomorrow. Sorry to disturb for such a stupid matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem : my iptable firewall ... I was blocking all the incoming traffic which was not an answer to my outgoing traffic. That's why I saw the traffic on wireshark but I didn't reached the java socket...

So the solution was to open my firewall -_-"